vue frontend with rails-api backend application not loading environment variables with nginx as a proxy in production mode
I have a .env.production file in which I have VITE_BACKEND_URL=http://www.example.net/api. This is the structure of my application
/MY_APP
  /app
  /frontend
    /src
    /public
    vite.config.js
    .env.production
  .env.production  

This is vite.config.js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  // Load env variables based on mode
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');

  console.log('VITE_BACKEND_URL:', env.VITE_BACKEND_URL);

  return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
      outDir: "../public",
      emptyOutDir: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        external: ['img/Flag_of_Anarcho-capitalism.png']
      }
    },
    css: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer],
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    },
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: env.VITE_BACKEND_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
          changeOrigin: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
});


This is the configuration file for Nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;

    # Serve static files from the Vite build output directory
    root /home/puma/MDL/public;

    # Error log configuration
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log debug;

    # Location for root path (serving Vite static files)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Proxy for API requests
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api;  # or use 127.0.0.1 if localhost doesn’t work
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # CORS headers for /api endpoints
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'access-token, expiry, token-type, Authorization' always;
    }

    # Proxy for /confirmation route
    location /confirmationFromVue {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api/confirmationFromVue;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Ensure pre-flight OPTIONS requests are handled properly
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type' always;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'access-token, expiry, token-type, Authorization' always;
           return 204;
       }
    }
    # Also handle /login directly if needed
    location ~ ^/(login|logout|signup|member-data) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api/$1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'access-token, expiry, token-type, Authorization' always;
    }

   # Modified confirmation location block to handle query parameters

    # Increase client body size limit
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    # Keep connection open for longer periods
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

    # Set default index files
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}


I have put a console.log in confirmEmail action in a javascript file in order to check the value of VITE_BACKEND_URL.
import { defineStore } from "pinia"

const BACKEND_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL
const TESTENV = import.meta.env.VITE_TEST_VAR

export const useSessionStore = defineStore({
    id: 'sessionStore',
    state: () => ({
        authToken: null,
        user: {},
        errors: [],
        registrationStatus: null
    }),

    getters: {
        getAuthToken() {
            return this.authToken
        },

        getUserEmail() {
            return this.user.email
        },

        getUserId() {
            return this.user.id
        },

        getUserUsername() {
            return this.user.username
        },

        isAdmin() {
            return this.user.admin
        },

        getUserDetails() {
            return this.user
        },

        getErrors() {
            return this.errors
        },

        isLoggedIn() {
            const loggedOut = this.authToken === null || this.authToken === JSON.stringify(null)
            return !loggedOut
        }
    },

    actions: {
        async registerUser(params) {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/signup`, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ user: params })
                })

                if (!res.ok) {
                    const error = await res.json()
                    this.errors = error.errors
                    console.log(`An error occurred: ${error.message}`)
                    return false
                }

                const data = await res.json()
                this.registrationStatus = 'pending_confirmation'
                // Don't set authToken or user data here

                return true
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`An error occurred: ${error}`)
                return false
            }
        },

        async confirmEmail(token) {
            console.log('BACKEND_URL', BACKEND_URL)
            console.log('TESTENV', TESTENV)

            try {
                const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/confirmationFromVue?confirmation_token=${token}`, {
                    method: "GET"
                })

                if (!res.ok) {
                    const error = await res.json()
                    this.errors = error.errors
                    console.log(`An error occurred during confirmation: ${error.message}`)
                    return false
                }

                const data = await res.json()
                // You might want to automatically log the user in here, or just update the status
                this.registrationStatus = 'confirmed'

                return true
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`An error occurred during confirmation: ${error}`)
                return false
            }
        },

        loginUser(params) {
            return this.handleUserForm(`${BACKEND_URL}/login`, params, "login")
        },

        updateUser(params) {
            return this.handleUserForm(`${BACKEND_URL}/signup`, params, "update")
        },

        async handleUserForm(url, params, action) {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(url, {
                    method: action === "update" ? "PATCH" : "POST",
                    headers: action === "update" ? { "Content-Type": "application/json", Authorization: this.authToken } : { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ user: params })
                })
                console.log('res', res)
                
                if (!res.ok) {
                    console.log('!res.ok', res);
        
                    let errorMessage = "An error occurred"; // Default message
        
                    // Check if response is JSON
                    const contentType = res.headers.get("content-type");
                    if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
                        try {
                            const errorData = await res.json();
                            errorMessage = errorData.message || errorMessage;
                        } catch (jsonError) {
                            console.log("Failed to parse JSON error response", jsonError);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Fallback: parse response as plain text
                        try {
                            errorMessage = await res.text();
                        } catch (textError) {
                            console.log("Failed to parse text error response", textError);
                        }
                    }
        
                    // Set error message for display
                    this.errors = [errorMessage];
                    console.log('this.errors', this.errors);
                    console.log(`An error occurred 1: ${errorMessage}`);
                    return false;
                }
        
                // console.log('handleUserForm', res)
                this.authToken = action === "update" ? this.authToken : res.headers.get("Authorization")
                localStorage.setItem("authToken", this.authToken)
                const data = await res.json()
                this.user = data.user
                return true
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`An error occured 26: ${error}`)
                return false
            }
        },

        async loginUserWithToken(token) {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/member-data`, {
                    headers: { Authorization: token }
                })
                if (!res.ok) {
                    const error = await res.json()
                    console.log(`An error occured while logging in: ${error.message}`) // eslint-disable-line no-console
                    this.reset()
                } else {
                    const data = await res.json()
                    console.log("dataaa logged in w token", data)
                    this.user = data.user
                    this.authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`An error occured while logging in: ${error}`) // eslint-disable-line no-console
            }
        },

        async logoutUser() {
            if (!this.authToken) {
                console.log("No authToken found, user might already be logged out");
                this.reset();
                return;
            }
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/logout`, {
                    method: "DELETE",
                    headers: { Authorization: this.authToken }
                })

                if (!res.ok) {
                    const error = await res.json()

                    console.log(`An error occured while logging out: ${error.message}`) // eslint-disable-line no-console
                    console.log('res', res)
                } else {
                    this.reset()
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`An error occured while logging out: ${error}`) // eslint-disable-line no-console
            }
        },

        reset() {
            this.$reset()
            localStorage.removeItem("authToken")
        },

        clearErrors() {
            this.errors = []
        },

        clearRegistrationStatus() {
            this.registrationStatus = null
        }
    }
})


It shows http://www.example.net instead of http://www.example.net/api.
When I run yarn build --mode production the terminal shows
puma@srv590617:~/MDL/frontend$ yarn build --mode production
yarn run v1.22.22
$ vite build --mode production
VITE_BACKEND_URL: http://www.example.net/api/
vite v5.4.11 building for production...

routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    scope '/api' do
    resources :xlsx_uploads, only: [:create]

    devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {
      sign_in: 'login',
      sign_out: 'logout',
      registration: 'signup'
    }, controllers: {
      sessions: 'api/users/sessions',
      registrations: 'api/users/registrations'
    }, skip: [:confirmations]

        devise_scope :user do
      get 'confirmationFromVue', to: 'api/users/registrations#confirm', as: :user_confirmation
    end

    get 'questions/export', to: 'xlsx_uploads#export_questions'
    get 'users/export', to: 'xlsx_uploads#export_users'

    resources :questions do
      collection do
        delete 'destroy_all'
        get 'index_admin', to: 'questions#index_admin'
      end
      resources :answers, only: [:index, :create]
    end

    resources :answers, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
    resources :scores
    resources :users, only: [:index]

    get "/questionnaire-params", to: 'questionnaire_params#index'
    put "/questionnaire-params", to: 'questionnaire_params#update'
    get "/uzer-scores", to: 'scores#user_scores'
    get "/member-data", to: "members#show"
    get "*path", to: "static#index", constraints: proc { |request| !request.xhr? && request.format.html? }
  end
end

Those are the routes
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                            xlsx_uploads POST   /api/xlsx_uploads(.:format)                                                                       xlsx_uploads#create
                        new_user_session GET    /api/login(.:format)                                                                              api/users/sessions#new
                            user_session POST   /api/login(.:format)                                                                              api/users/sessions#create
                    destroy_user_session DELETE /api/logout(.:format)                                                                             api/users/sessions#destroy
                cancel_user_registration GET    /api/signup/cancel(.:format)                                                                      api/users/registrations#cancel
                   new_user_registration GET    /api/signup/sign_up(.:format)                                                                     api/users/registrations#new
                  edit_user_registration GET    /api/signup/edit(.:format)                                                                        api/users/registrations#edit
                       user_registration PATCH  /api/signup(.:format)                                                                             api/users/registrations#update
                                         PUT    /api/signup(.:format)                                                                             api/users/registrations#update
                                         DELETE /api/signup(.:format)                                                                             api/users/registrations#destroy
                                         POST   /api/signup(.:format)                                                                             api/users/registrations#create
                       user_confirmation GET    /api/confirmationFromVue(.:format)                                                                api/users/registrations#confirm
                        questions_export GET    /api/questions/export(.:format)                                                                   xlsx_uploads#export_questions
                            users_export GET    /api/users/export(.:format)                                                                       xlsx_uploads#export_users
                   destroy_all_questions DELETE /api/questions/destroy_all(.:format)                                                              questions#destroy_all
                   index_admin_questions GET    /api/questions/index_admin(.:format)                                                              questions#index_admin
                        question_answers GET    /api/questions/:question_id/answers(.:format)                                                     answers#index
                                         POST   /api/questions/:question_id/answers(.:format)                                                     answers#create
                               questions GET    /api/questions(.:format)                                                                          questions#index
                                         POST   /api/questions(.:format)                                                                          questions#create
                                question GET    /api/questions/:id(.:format)                                                                      questions#show
                                         PATCH  /api/questions/:id(.:format)                                                                      questions#update
                                         PUT    /api/questions/:id(.:format)                                                                      questions#update
                                         DELETE /api/questions/:id(.:format)                                                                      questions#destroy
                                  answer GET    /api/answers/:id(.:format)                                                                        answers#show
                                         PATCH  /api/answers/:id(.:format)                                                                        answers#update
                                         PUT    /api/answers/:id(.:format)                                                                        answers#update
                                         DELETE /api/answers/:id(.:format)                                                                        answers#destroy
                                  scores GET    /api/scores(.:format)                                                                             scores#index
                                         POST   /api/scores(.:format)                                                                             scores#create
                                   score GET    /api/scores/:id(.:format)                                                                         scores#show
                                         PATCH  /api/scores/:id(.:format)                                                                         scores#update
                                         PUT    /api/scores/:id(.:format)                                                                         scores#update
                                         DELETE /api/scores/:id(.:format)                                                                         scores#destroy
                                   users GET    /api/users(.:format)                                                                              users#index
                    questionnaire_params GET    /api/questionnaire-params(.:format)                                                               questionnaire_params#index
                                         PUT    /api/questionnaire-params(.:format)                                                               questionnaire_params#update
                             uzer_scores GET    /api/uzer-scores(.:format)                                                                        scores#user_scores
                             member_data GET    /api/member-data(.:format)                                                                        members#show
                                         GET    /api/*path(.:format)                                                                              static#index

When doing the build, the VITE_BACKEND_URL variable is correctly read (VITE_BACKEND_URL: http://www.example.net/api/) but the console log in the pinia store shows BACKEND_URL http://www.example.net. I need help.

do you have any other console logs you may be confusing the result with?  I would expect undefined being logged in your terminal since env variables require special handling in vite.config as answered here.  Your other problem is I think a misunderstanding, vite dev server is for development, not production, though there is a way to run it in "production mode", seen here

All I am doing is in production. I run yarn build to build the frontend and then I run rails s.

so your production setup has rails serving your vue app, not vite.  The vite dev server, which is what normally serves a vue app when running yarn dev is not included in the yarn build production bundle, therefore the server settings are useless in production environment.  for production you need to set up proxy another way.  I'm not familiar enough with rails to offer equivalent solution.  If using a library like axios it would be enough to set baseURL and solve it that way.

Indeed, vite is only running in development mode. I do yarn build to build the frontend files and rails serves them. Nginx is the proxy that redirect requests to rails for api-requests and to the frontend for non-api requests. I have edited my question, there are now more details.
